SAML configuration broke after upgrade from 7.55.8 to 7.98.8
We've recently upgraded our Artifactory to the latest version. Most things seem to work but our existing SAML configuration broke. When trying to login we get:
{"errors":[{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"HTTP 500 Internal Server Error","detail":"entityId cannot be empty"}]}
In the documentation entityId or Service provider id is referred to as a URI. In our configuration from 7.55.8 it is, however, not a URI.
I tried reconfiguring the settings under a different name than default but it's the same issue. When I try inspecting the network traffic, I don't see any connections to our Keycloak instance.
Also tried configuring the Service Provider Id as a URI.
Does any one have any suggestions?

So, I really really really hate this...
When debugging we found that we needed to set the baseURL as our Keycloak client name. Then it worked.
After this we've upgraded our production environment and get this, the stupid problem didn't occur... Everything is still the same as it was before.
I have no idea what went wrong or why it works now but it does...

is the custom base url is set in Artifactory?
curl -u<:> https://<artifactory_url>/artifactory/api/system/configuration/platform/baseUrl

similar to the google configuration (https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/saml-sso-configuration-with-google)
the saml service provider name should be
the entity ID from Keycloak.
and in Keycloak setting you need to change the ACS URL should be in this format:
<CustomURL>/ui/api/v1/auth/saml/loginResponse/<saml_display_name>
and SP Identity is the <CustomURL>

Hi! So adding a custom base url helped somewhat. Now Artifactory tries to connect to Keycloak. We're now getting a "Invalid request" in Keycloak.
When I try to analyse the SAML request, i don't seem to find a ProviderName. This is something we could find in our older installation.
